# IntrinsicContentSize on a custom UIView streches the content

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, intrinsic-content-size

I would like to create a custom `UIView` which uses/offers a IntrinsicContentSize, since its height depends on its content (just like a label where the height depends on the text).

While I found a lot of information on how to work with IntrinsicContentSize offered by existing Views, I found just a few bits on how to use IntrinsicContentSize on a custom `UIView`:

```
@IBDesignable class MyIntrinsicView: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context?.setFillColor(UIColor.gray.cgColor)
        context?.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: 25))
        
        height = 300
        invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
    
    
    @IBInspectable var height: CGFloat = 50
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: super.intrinsicContentSize.width, height: height)
    }
    
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
}
```

- The initial high is set to `50`
- The `draw` methods draws a gray rect with a size `25`
- height is changed to `300` and `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()` is called
- Placing a `MyView` instance in InterfaceBuilder works without any problem. The view does not need a height constraint

However, in IB the initial height of `50` is used. **Why?** IB draws the gray rect, thus the `draw` method is called. So why is the height not changed to 300?

What is also strange: When setting a background color it is drawn as well, also `super.draw(...)` is not called. Is this intended?

I would expect a view with height of `300` and a gray rect at the top with a height of `25`. However, when running the project in simulator the result is different:

- height of the view = `300` - **OK**
- height of content (= gray rect) = 150 (half view height) - **NOT OK**

**It seems that the content was stretched from its original height of `25` to keep its relative height to the view. Why is this?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to change the view's height from inside `draw()` is probably a really bad idea.

First, as you've seen, changing the intrinsic content size does not trigger a redraw. Second, if it did, your code would go into an infinite recursion loop.

Take a look at this edit to your class:

```
@IBDesignable class MyIntrinsicView: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context?.setFillColor(UIColor.gray.cgColor)
        context?.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: 25))

        // probably a really bad idea to do this inside draw()
        //height = 300
        //invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
    
    
    @IBInspectable var height: CGFloat = 50 {
        didSet {
            // call when height var is set
            invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
            // we need to trigger draw()
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: super.intrinsicContentSize.width, height: height)
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        // not needed
        //invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
}
```

Now, when you change the intrinsic height in IB via the `IBDesignable` property, it will update in your Storyboard properly.

Here's a quick look at using it at run-time. Each tap (anywhere) will increase the `height` property by 50 (until we get over 300, when it will be reset to 50), which then invalidates the intrinsic content size and forces a call to `draw()`:

```
class QuickTestVC: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var testView: MyIntrinsicView!
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        var h: CGFloat = testView.intrinsicContentSize.height
        h += 50
        if h > 300 {
            h = 50
        }
        testView.height = h
    }
}
```