# UITableView + AutoLayout + Intrinsic Size: Where/when to calculate size?

Tags: ios, uitableview, intrinsic-content-size

I have create a custom view `MyIntrincView` which calculates its height automatically when setting its content. This works fine both in simulator and InterfaceBuilder.

However, when placing `MyIntrinsicView` inside a `UITableViewCell`, the cell height is **not** calculated correctly. Instead of automatically adopting the cell height to the intrinsic height of the view, all cell keep the same, initial height.

```
// A simple, custom view with intrinsic height. The height depends on
// the value of someProperty. When the property is changed setNeedsLayout
// is set and the height changes automatically.
@IBDesignable class MyIntrinsicView: UIView {
    @IBInspectable public var someProperty: Int = 5 {
        didSet { setNeedsLayout() }
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        calcContent()
    }
    
    func calcContent() {
        height = CGFloat(20 * someProperty)
        invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
    
    
    @IBInspectable var height: CGFloat = 50
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: super.intrinsicContentSize.width, height: height)
    }
    
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
}


// A simple cell which only contains a MyIntrinsicView subview. The view
// is attached to trailing, leading, top and bottom anchors of the cell.
// Thus the cell height should automatically match the height of the
// MyIntrinsicView
class MyIntrinsicCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet private var myIntrinsicView: MyIntrinsicView!
    
    var someProperty: Int {
        get { return myIntrinsicView.someProperty }
        set {
            myIntrinsicView.someProperty = newValue
            
            // Cell DOES NOT rezise without manualle calling layoutSubviews()
            myIntrinsicView.layoutSubviews()
        }
    }
}

...
// Simple tableView delegate which should create cells of different heights 
// by giving each cell a different someProperty 
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "IntrinsicCell", for: indexPath) as? MyIntrinsicCell ?? MyIntrinsicCell()
    
    // Give all cell a different intrinsic height by setting someProperty to rowIndex
    cell.someProperty = indexPath.row
    return cell
}
```

I would expect, that each cell has a different height (`20 * someProperty` = `20 * indexPath.row`). However, instead all cell have the same, initial height.

Only when explicitly calling `myIntrinsicView.layoutSubviews()` the cells are created with the correct height.

It seems that the tableView does not call `myIntrinsicView.layoutSubviews()`. **Why is this?**

When using a `UILabel` instad of `MyIntrinsicView` as cell content with different text lengths, everything works as expected. Thus the overall tableView setup is correct (= cell sizes are calculated automatically) and there has to be way to use intrinsic sizes correctly in `UITableView` as well. **So, what exactly is the correct way to do this?**

Answer (score 0):

As with your previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67925107/intrinsiccontentsize-on-a-custom-uiview-streches-the-content) I think you're not really understanding what `intrinsicContentSize` does and does not do.

When setting the text of a `UILabel`, yes, its `intrinsicContentSize` changes, but that's not all that happens.

You also don't want to do what you're trying inside `layoutSubviews()` ... if your code **does** trigger a change, you'll get into an infinite recursion loop (again, as with your previous question).

Take a look at modifications to your code:

```
// A simple, custom view with intrinsic height. The height depends on
// the value of someProperty. When the property is changed setNeedsLayout
// is set and the height changes automatically.
@IBDesignable class MyIntrinsicView: UIView {
    @IBInspectable public var someProperty: Int = 5 {
        didSet {
            calcContent()
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    
    func calcContent() {
        height = CGFloat(20 * someProperty)
        invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
    
    
    @IBInspectable var height: CGFloat = 50
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: super.intrinsicContentSize.width, height: height)
    }
    
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
}


// A simple cell which only contains a MyIntrinsicView subview. The view
// is attached to trailing, leading, top and bottom anchors of the cell.
// Thus the cell height should automatically match the height of the
// MyIntrinsicView
class MyIntrinsicCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet private var myIntrinsicView: MyIntrinsicView!
    
    var someProperty: Int {
        get { return myIntrinsicView.someProperty }
        set {
            myIntrinsicView.someProperty = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Two side notes...

1 - Your posted code shows you calling `myIntrinsicView.layoutSubviews()`... from Apple's docs:

> You should not call this method directly. If you want to force a layout update, call the setNeedsLayout method instead to do so prior to the next drawing update. If you want to update the layout of your views immediately, call the layoutIfNeeded method.

2 - For the direction it looks like you're headed, you would probably be better off manipulating constraint constants, rather than intrinsic content size.

Comment: Thanks again for your excellent answer! The real intrinsic view has multiple properties which effect the intrinsic height. Link in the UILabel the height depends on text length and font size. When setting up the view and setting all the properties one after the other I would like to avoid that `calcContent()` is called multiple times. It would be enough to call it once after all properties are set. This is why I decided to call `calcContent()` in `layoutSubviews()` instead of in the property `didSet`. Thus, is there another approach than to create one big setter for all properties?

Comment: @AndreiHerford - it is really unusual to manipulate `intrinsicContentSize` this way. In general, we use auto-layout / constraints on a view's subviews to manage the sizing. I've seen some **very** complex layouts - and put some together myself - and in only very specific cases have they used this `intrinsicContentSize` type of approach. I *really* think you're misunderstanding this aspect of layout. Maybe if you clarify and show exactly what your going for it would make sense...

Comment: Assume a simple Tag-List: A view which gets a string array as input and shows a formated tag list as output. Each tag/word draws with a background. Other than with a normal label the size/height is not only determined by text/tags and font but also by item and row spacing, background to text padding, etc. Of course this could also be solved using a CollectionView or by adding Lables as subviews and use autoLayout constraints on them. However, especially when embedded in a TableView, etc. a specialized, plain view would be much more efficient, wouldn't it?

Comment: @AndreiHerford - *"I would like to avoid that calcContent() is called multiple times"* ... well, you could either set a "needsCalc" type of flag, or explicitly call `calcContent()` after you've set all the properties. As far as would a *"specialized, plain view"* be more efficient? Not necessarily ... In fact, it might be **less** efficient. Personally, I would take the approach of coding it in the most reliable, straight-forward way, and **then** look for ways to optimize it ***if needed***.

Comment: Thank you again for you answer. You are correct, that *"I do not really understanding what intrinsicContentSize does and does not do"*. However, the problem is that I found no source which really explains it...  Thus I have spend several hours trying to understand how to correctly use intrinsicSize without little progress. The comment field is too short to explain all my questions and to answer your message. I will create a new, more precise question and delete this one... https://stackoverflow.com/q/67974271/777861